# Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45 stbuild Error after update

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45 stbuild Error after update

I updated my CMD for Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45 and when I run:

```
sencha app build native
```

It says:

```
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Sencha Native Package (stbuild) is currently unsupported on linux
[ERR]     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapte
[ERR] r.java:154)
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 10 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/daniel/Desktop/mobile/p2_arch3/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:422: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/daniel/Desktop/mobile/p2_arch3/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:112: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/daniel/Desktop/mobile/p2_arch3/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:114: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/daniel/Desktop/mobile/p2_arch3/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:98: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/daniel/Desktop/mobile/p2_arc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know the OS you are working on. If you are running in Linux, stbuild won't be helpful. Please use cordova or phonegap. Please refer [the link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?275924-Sencha-Cmd-v4.0.1.45-stbuild-Error-after-update)

Comment: I don't know why they have a sencha architect configuration for linux to work with mobile if they don't support it... and there's no documentation about that in sencha page...